# how to refresh the page underneath after closing the modal?

Tags: jquery, ajax

my application goes like this, user fills the form, the if he's not logged in or registered, once the submit button is clicked, a jquery modal box appears which contains registration fields, after the user fills in the modal fields and click register button, this modal closes and inserts the registration details of the new member.

now the question is, how to refresh the same page, after the modal closes, to make the page show the current user is a registered member ?, I just want to know how to refresh the page underneath,,

here's what i have at the moment

```
 if(userid == ""){
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 230,
        width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Register": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                $('div#registerpopup').dialog({
                   resizable: false,
                   height: 485,
                   width: 420,
                   modal: true,
                   buttons: {
                        "Register": function(){
                            var username = $('#username').val();
                            var password = $('#password').val();
                            var retypepassword = $('#retypepassword').val();
                            var emailaddress = $('#emailaddress').val();
                            var secondaryemailaddress = $('#secondaryemailaddress').val();
                            var secretquestion = $('#secretquestion').val();
                            var secretanswer = $('#secretanswer').val();
                            var reffcode = $('#reffcode').val();
                            var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
                          if(username == "" || username.length < 1 || username.length > 30 || username.indexOf(' ') != -1){
                            alert("Username is required\n-should not be less than 1 character\n-should not be more than 30 characters\n-It may also not contain spaces");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(password.length < 7 || password.indexOf(' ') !=  -1 ){
                            alert("Password should not be empty\n-should at least be 7 characters");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(retypepassword != password){
                            alert("re-type password should be the same as the password!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(emailaddress == "" || emailaddress.search(emailRegEx) == -1){
                            alert("Email Address is required and should be a valid email address");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secondaryemailaddress == "" || secondaryemailaddress.search(emailRegEx) == -1){
                            alert("Secondary Email address should be the same as the primary email address!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secretquestion == ""){
                            alert("Secret Question is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(secretanswer == ""){
                            alert("Secret Answer is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          if(reffcode == ""){
                            alert("Reference Code is required!");
                            return false;
                          }
                          else {
                            $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "classes/ajax.registerpopup.php",
                               timeout: 8000,
                               data: "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&emailaddress="+emailaddress+
                                     "&secondaryemailaddress="+secondaryemailaddress+"&secretquestion="+secretquestion+
                                     "&secretanswer="+secretanswer+"&reffcode="+reffcode,
                               success: function(){
                                 alert("You are now registered!");
                               }
                            });
                          }
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                   }
                });
                },
                "Log in": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                $('div#loginpopup').dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height: 230,
                  width: 350,
                  modal: true
                })
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full page to be refreshed, can't you call

```
window.location = 'pathToCurrentPage'
```

after the modal closes? This would force the page to refresh.

From User Experience point of view it might be better to just update the part of the page that shows a user is logged in

Comment: that's my problem actually, there's a login box at the upper right corner of the page, I want to refresh the page after the jquery modal closes, is that even possible to do? like show the currently registered user as logged-in ?

Comment: you mean, put that `window.location ='pathToCurrentPage'` under this line ? `$(this).dialog("close");`

Comment: @sasori - It depends on how you designed the page. If the loginbox is for example a div with id loginBox you could use jquery like this

`$("#loginBox").hide()`

to hide the login box and after that use 

`$("#loggedInUser").show()`

to show a div containing the userdetails. 

Refreshing can be done in the way I described or like KhanZeeshan did.

Comment: @sasori - in this part of your code `success: function(){
                                 alert("You are now registered!");
                               }`
You could just reload the page by replacing the alert with the `window.location ='pathToCurrentPage'` but you could also hide the userlogin box and show the userdetails

Comment: @JeroenZ This should do the same: `window.location = ''`

Answer (score 0):

Call this function on the close event of popup:

```
document.parent.location.reload();
```